# OpenCart 3.x - syntax issue with IF/ELSE loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I have some code in OpenCart 2.0 template file, that includes this block:

```
<?php if($stock >= 1) { ?>
    (block of HTML #1)
<? } else { ?>
    (block of HTML #2)
<? } ?>
```

Attempting to implement the same in OpenCart 3.0 template, that uses the Twig language, results in "= 1) { ?>" showing up on the front end, followed by *both* HTML blocks.

I've looked at the OpenCart Twig documentation, but it's not clear what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone can provide an example of the proper code, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you can see how to echo a variable and how to compare it in twig:

```
stock is: {{ stock }}
<br>

{% if stock >= 1 %}
    (block of HTML #1)
{% else %}
    (block of HTML #2)
{% endif %}
```